# get Phone numbers from android phone

Tags: java, android

First of all i'm sorry for my english...

I've a problem getting phone numbers from contacts.

That's my code

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class TestContacts extends ListActivity {


private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

 private SimpleAdapter numbers;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
  numbers = new SimpleAdapter( 
    this, 
list,
R.layout.main_item_two_line_row,
new String[] { "line1","line2" },
new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 }  );
  setListAdapter( numbers );



  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
    null, null, null, null); 
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
   String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
   String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 

                    //check if the contact has a phone number
   if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 

Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
  null, 
  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
  null, null); 
while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
 // Get the phone number!?

 String contactName = phones.getString( 
   phones.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

 String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
   phones.getColumnIndex( 
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 
 Toast.makeText(this, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     

 drawContact(contactName, phoneNumber);

} 
phones.close(); 
   } 
  }cursor.close();
 }

 private void drawContact(String name, String number){

  HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
  item.put( "line1",name);
  item.put( "line2",number);
  list.add( item );
  numbers.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }

}
```

It'seems that no contact have a phone number (i've added 2 contacts on the emulator and i've tried also on my HTC Desire). The problem is that 
if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
returns always false.. 
How can i get correctly phone numbers?

I've tried to call drawContact(String name, String number) before the if statement without querying for the phone number, and it worked (it draws two times the name). but on the LinearLayout they are not ordered alphabetically... how can i order alphabetically (similar to the original contacts app)?

thank you in advice,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean(java.lang.String)) for parseBoolean().
You might want to try parsing the result into an int instead of a boolean.